# rcp internationalization, change language, with config.ini

Tags: java, internationalization, eclipse-rcp, configuration-files, rcp

I want to internationalise my rcp application.
Therefor I want to write the runtime parameter "-Dosgi.nl=xy" in the launcher ini file.

But the launcher ini is write-protected in the install directory.

How can I change the location of the "yourproduct.ini"?
Or can I set the parameter -Dosgi.nl=xl in the config.ini?

Kind regards
Markus

Comment: You can set the parameter in your config.ini

Comment: thanks for your hint. Now it works with the config.ini :)

Answer (score 0):

If you start your application from command line you can configure which ini file is used:

```
rcp-app.exe --launcher.ini yourproduct.ini
```